# Getting the text from a QTextEdit inside a QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a `QTabWidget` 'tw' to which I add tabs like this:

```
QWidget *newTab = new QWidget(tw);
tw->addTab(newTab, "Tab name");
QTextEdit *te = new QTextEdit();
te->setText("Hello world");
QVBoxLayout *vbox = new QVBoxLayout();
vbox->addWidget(te);
newTab->setLayout(vbox);
```

How can I get the text inside the `QTextEdit` from the tab that is in the foreground (like when I click a button I'd like to copy the text from the visible tab to the clipboard or smtg like that). I don't know how to get a handle of the `QTextEdit`.

Comment: `te->toPlaintText()` ?

Comment: I need a handle to te in order to do that. I don't have one. All I know is that the tab containing it is in the foreground.

Comment: So add your `QTextEdit` as a member of a widget that contains your `QTabWidget`.

Comment: I don't get it. It's the first time I make a program in Qt. Be a little bit more explicit please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep track of your text edits manually. Either through storing a pointer to them in a parent widget, or you could make use of a lookup table, e.g. a [QHash](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qhash.html#details):

Assuming you have a class `MyClass` which contains the code you posted in your question:

Add a member variable like this:

```
class QTextEdit; // this is a so-called "Forward Declaration" which saves you an
                 // #include. Google it if you want to know more ;-)
class MyClass
{
    // ...
private:

    QHash< int, QTextEdit* > _textEditPerTabPage;
};
```

This variable makes it possible to store (and find) the text edit from the index (0, 1, 2, ...) of your tab pages.

You could do an add function like this:

```
void MyClass::addTab( QTabWidget* tabWidget, const QString& tabName, const QString& text )
{
    // Create the text edit
    QTextEdit* textEdit = new QTextEdit();
    textEdit->setText( text );

    // Create a layout which contains the text edit
    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    layout->addWidget( textEdit );

    // Create a parent widget for the layout
    QWidget* newTab = new QWidget( tabWidget );
    newTab->setLayout( layout );

    // Add that widget as a new tab
    int tabIndex = tabWidget->addTab( newTab, tabName );

    // Remember the text edit for the widget
    _textEditPerTabPage.insert( tabIndex, textEdit );
}
```

And then retrieve a pointer on the `QTextEdit` like this:

```
QTextEdit* textEdit = _textEditPerTabPage.value( tabWidget->currentIndex() );
```

This code has a couple of limitations, e.g. you always have to make sure you use your own `MyClass::addTab` function and don't access `QTabWidget::addTab` outside of that function. Also if you call `QTabWidget::removeTab`, your `QHash` may no longer point to the proper QTextEdits.

Comment: Where would the QWidget* tabWidget come from? If I were to make this a standalone button, would I really need the QWidget* tabWidget? Could I just do `this->parentWidget()` instead?

Comment: @developer01 The method I provided needs a QTabWidget since it calls `addTab` (I edited my answer since it wrongly asked for a QWidget*).
The author of the question had a problem with an existing `QTabWidget` so it looks like you have a completely different problem here

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you for clarifying. I greatly appreciate it.